# Last checked row in datagridview checkbox column is not checked

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have DataGridView populated from excel file.
I added checkbox column to this datagridview

```
...
dtSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("boolCol", typeof(bool)));
dgvInputFile.DataSource = dtSet.Tables[0];
dgvInputFile.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Later I'm checking if each row is cheked:

```
  for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < grv.Rows.Count; currentRow++)
  {
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CbxCell = dgvInputFile.Rows[currentRow].Cells["boolCol"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
   bool valid = CbxCell != null && !DBNull.Value.Equals(CbxCell.Value) && (bool)CbxCell.Value == true; 
    ....
```

If i check the first row. Then `valid=false` for any row. 
If i check the first 2 rows. Then `valid=true` only for the first row. 
If i check the first 3 rows. Then `valid=true` only for the first two rows. 
It seems like the last row is always unchecked. But it's cheked. And this is not only when i'm checking from the beginning.

I tried second method for determining if the row is cheked and the result is same.

```
(bool)dgvInputFile.Rows[currentRow].Cells["boolCol"].FormattedValue
```

In addition. If i check the first, then the second, and the third and **unceck the third** work fine.

Comment: does the `currentRow` actually pointing to 3rd row (or) the row you intend to check?

Comment: Yes. I checked this. Only the value of the checkbox cell is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found what cause this behavior.
Last checked checkbox is still in edit mode when i'm getting his value with `(bool)dgvInputFile.Rows[currentRow].Cells["boolCol"].FormattedValue`

Insted i should use `DataGridViewCell.EditedFormattedValue` property.

MSDN

```
Gets the current, formatted value of the cell, 
regardless of whether the cell is in edit mode 
and the value has not been committed.
```